# Minimal Ideal of a Commutative Ring with Unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Can anyone help me prove this? This one is from Malik's *Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra*.

An ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is called a *minimal* ideal if $I≠{0}$ and there does not exist any ideal $J$ of R such that ${0}≠J⊂I$.

> If $I$ is a minimal ideal of a commutative ring $R$ with $1$, show that either $I^2={0}$ or $I=eR$ for some idempotent $e∈R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $I^2 \neq 0$, then $\exists a\in I$ such that $aI \neq 0$. Hence, $aI = I$, and so $\exists e\in I$ such that $ae = a$.

Now, $J = (e^2-e)R \subset I$ and $J\neq I$ (because if $J=I$, then $aI = a(e^2-e)R = 0$), and hence $J = 0$, whence $e$ is an idempotent and $I = eR$.

Comment: There is a detail I am missing. Could you please explain why $a(e^2−e)R=0$.

Comment: @RodneyColeman $a(e^2-e)=aee-ae=ae-ae=0$.

Comment: Many thanks. I should have seen it.

Comment: @Prahlad could you explain how $J=(e^2-e)R$ is a subset of $I$